# AWS Amplify and Vue router history mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, vue-router, aws-amplify

I have a Vue app that uses Vue router. Now I'm supposed to make a website for a client where one part is "secret" and can only be accessed through a direct link.

In other words, I want users to be able to navigate to myamplifyapp.com/mysecretpage just by entering this in the address bar.

I heard this works with Vue router history mode, set it up locally (apache) and everything is working well, but when I'm deploying it on Amplify, I can't access this page directly through a link, instead it just goes to `index.html`. Is there any way I can configure Amplify to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa) to point users to `index.html`.

Something like this should work:

`/<*> /index.html 200`.

You'll probably want js/css files to not be redirected. For that you can try the reg exp from the link.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself sufficiently clear. I updated the question... I want them to be able to go to a specific part of the page through the address bar. Either way, thanks even if only for the link, that's valuable!